# Windows spanning 2 monitors resize themselves onto 1 after screen saver is started (Win XP)

Tags: multiple-monitors, screensaver

I have a dual monitor setup with an ATI Radeon HD 3450 driving 2 Dell 1907FPs in *Extended* mode.  The video driver is ATI's 8.561-081201a1-073177C-Dell.

Onscreen, I have a couple of non-maximised windows that I resize to span the 2 monitors.  When the screensaver (any screensaver) starts (or finishes, I'm not sure), the windows are automatically resized so that they fit on one of the monitors only.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the lastest Catalyst Control Center downloaded from AMD, not from Dell, (after uninstalling the current version, if applicable) which will also install the latest driver. If you still run into problems, go into Catalyst Control Center (Advanced View) and click Displays Manager. Verify the settings there.

If it still happens, try the ATI forums; they are pretty helpful.