# Windows 7: Dual Monitor Issue

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell laptop with a docking station and two external monitors hooked up. I'm running Windows 7 64 bit.

Originally, the two monitors were the same - Dell 1908FP.  I have replaced one of them with an HP LA2405.  I have set the HP 24" (1920 x 1200 connected via DVI port) as montior 1 and extended to use the Dell 19" (12080 x 1024 connected via VGA port) as monitor 2.

I have set my power plan so that when the laptop is plugged in, it will turn the monitors off after 10 minutes, but it will not put my laptop to sleep.

However, now that I have the HP monitor, when I unlock my laptop and the monitors come back on, all my windows are resized and shifted to the top left corner of the HP monitor as if they had been resized for display on the smaller Dell monitor.

A co-worker has the exact same laptop and monitor configuration but doesn't experience this issue, so I figure there's some configuration that's different but we can't find it.

I haven't been able to find any mention of a similar problem doing an internet search, but I'm not really sure what terms to use in my search.

Anybody have any suggestions as to what may be causing the issue?  OS setting?  Monitor setting?

EDIT:

My laptop is using the Intel Graphics and Media Control Panel/drivers.

Comment: Similar: http://superuser.com/questions/66520/windows-spanning-2-monitors-resize-themselves-onto-1-after-screen-saver-is-start

Comment: Similar, but not the same. When both my monitors were the same, I had no resize issues even if a window spanned both monitors.

Comment: just because you did not mention it: have you installed the latest drivers and updates?

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch - Good answer.  Also, subsequently, have you tried installing the same drivers that your co-worker has, since there's seems to work okay?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the drivers and it hasn't made a difference.  I have narrowed it down to being triggered when the HP monitor is turned off (screen saver activation doesn't trigger it). When the monitor is turned off (either manually or by the OS due to idle) when the monitor is turned back on, it does the resize/move of all my windows.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a driver or docking station issue. You can try to manually set the resolution of each monitor in the Intel Graphics utility. If that doesn't work, use msconfig to prevent the utility from launching and let windows manage the screen resolutions. You might get better results depending on how the screens get detected.

This is one of the reasons you should only use monitors that are the same resolution. Microsoft tries to make it better each time a new OS is out, but they have never got it perfect.

Sometimes, we just have to live with quirky machines.